# Use JSON Array in UITable iOS 7 and expand one row in another View

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

let's think about having a JSON array, filled of events, structured in this way:

```
-Title;
-Day;
-Photo;
-Description;
```

I have a View Controller where's the table that contains all events gained by HTTPRequest, but I've only to show two datas in the table: as Title of course, the title of the event, in the description, the day of that event. In the method **cellForRowAtIndexPath** I wrote this code:

```
cell.textLabel.text = EventiJSON[indexPath.row][@"titolo"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=EventiJSON[indexPath.row][@"data"];
```

Instead in the **viewDidLoad** I wrote this one:

```
self.ListaEventi.dataSource = self;
self.ListaEventi.delegate = self;
NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://www.fr4ncxlabs.net/almancava/almancava/news.php"];

NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

NSError *error;


int i=0;

EventiJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

if (!error){

    for (i=1; i<(EventiJSON.count);i++) {


    }
}
else{

}
```

But I don't know how to code that table must be filled only with that two attributes (title and data).

Moreover, I've another view, linked with tableview so that if you click on a row, you will be send on this view where you can see again the title, the day and also the photo and the description of the event.

This is the code in TableView Controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //mettere l'elemento della tabella seleziona con tutti i campi da passare alla view     dettagliata

    DetailViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.myString=@"titolo";
}
```

Does anyone could help me?

Comment: What is actually the problem? Are you seeing an error? Based on that JSON, the way you are accessing the leaves in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` looks fine.

Comment: Well so that mustn't I write anything in viewDidLoad? That for cycle isn't necessary?

Comment: Correct, you don't need the `for` loop.

Comment: Well i got some error due to thread killing...